# What replaced long as a field type from Solr 6 to Solr 7?

Tags: solr, lucene, migration

I'm migrating from Solr 6.6 to Solr 7.5.  In building my schema, I got the following error...

```
    "add-field":{
      "name":"fkId",
      "type":"long",
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":true},
    "errorMessages":["Field 'fkId': Field type 'long' not found.\n"]},
```

What replaced 'long' as a type from Solr 6.6 to 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the field types are in your *managed-schema* file, so you can exam directly and compare on a filesystem (for non-Cloud setup) or in Admin UI.

Specifically, for longs, the original definition was Trie based which are deprecated. So, now Point-based implementation is preferred and is the only one included. So, you can just switch to *plong* instead.

Or you can include the original *long* definition and keep using it. The Trie-based implementation are deprecated, but are still used due to some speed-related use-cases.

Comment: Also be aware that switching to the Point type will require rebuilding the index.